# How would i optimise this if statement

Tags: c#

Im finally done with my project and im going through my code and optimising it and trying to cut down on the chunky lines of code, how would i optimize this, it a series of if statments that matches text and adds value to a corresponding text box

```
private void btnfinalize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < POSDGV.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Manga vol 1-5 ")
                {                   
                    Global.Book1 = 1 + Global.Book1;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Manga vol 6-15 ")
                {
                    Global.Book2 = 1 + Global.Book2;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Novels 1-199 ")
                {
                    Global.Book3 = 1 + Global.Book3;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Novels 200-400 ")
                {
                    Global.Book4 = 1 + Global.Book4;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Comics series mainstream ")
                {
                    Global.Book5 = 1 + Global.Book5;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Comics series secondary ")
                {
                    Global.Book6 = 1 + Global.Book6;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Text book 1 semester/2 modules ")
                {
                    Global.Book7 = 1 + Global.Book7;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Text book module add-ons ")
                {
                    Global.Book8 = 1 + Global.Book8;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Hardcover ")
                {
                    Global.Hardcover = 1 + Global.Hardcover;
                }
            }
            }
```

Thx for any help

Comment: Start with removing repeating code: store this `POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()` and compare that with the literals.

Comment: Welcome to code review where we review working code and provide suggestions on how to improve that code. Unfortunately there isn't enough code in this question to provide a context for a code review. We would like to see how the function is used within the class or program. I suspect this is why @anki answered in a comment rather than providing a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary with keys being the strings you're testing and values that are the corresponding book.

```
IDictionary<string, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
myDictionary.Add("Manga vol 1-5 ", Global.Book1);
// and so on
```

Then simply use something like

```
myDictionary[POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()]++
```